# Vlookup Not Working - Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2016

Up until right now, I would've considered myself a vlookup expert.  I am SO confused why my vlookup is not working.  The values I am referencing should absolutely be returning data, but they're not.  I have checked the format of the numbers & looked for random data errors (rogue spaces, etc) many times & cannot figure out what is wrong here.  I've included a snip below.  I've also played around with the positioning of the $ with no luck.

[Click for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0D9j.jpg)

Comment: Is one column formatted as text and the other as numeric? The vlookup, as written, looks fine, so your snip doesn't really help reveal any issue.

Comment: Then H4 does not exist in D4:D2398.

Comment: Also do you not want the rows in the lookup range to be absolute? `$D$4:$E$2398`

Comment: @JNevill I have the whole page formatted as general.  Do you suggest I format it as anything else?

Comment: @ScottCraner The part I can't figure out it that H4 values do indeed exist in D4:D2398

Comment: Perhaps `=TRIM()` all the values in the D column and then copy and paste-values over the top of D. There may be a non-breaking space or tab character hiding out in there.

Comment: Your "numbers" in column D are most likely text that looks like numbers while you values in H are truly numbers.

Comment: @ScottCraner Also I tried the $D$4 as well as $D4 and even D$4 to be sure and no dice

Comment: Also, instead of trim, you can highlight column D and "Text to Columns" the whole thing so it reformats it all as numeric without much effort. It's 99.9999999999999999% unlikely that your vlookup is broken, but rather a data formatting (or rogue white space) issue.

Comment: Try this, do a simple equation `=H4=D###` where `D###` that you think should match.  If it is FALSE then figure out why.

Comment: @catherinemallory It does not matter what formatting is applied to cells. Applying formatting [does not automatically change the value type](https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365).

Comment: @ScottCraner I formatted all of the "numbers" to general and it still didn't work.  I've always used "general" in my vlookups, would you suggest something else?

Comment: The format of the cell will not change text, so if the values are text that look like numbers they will remain text that look like numbers.  You will need to actually convert them.  Try this: `=VLOOKUP($H4&"",$D$4:$E$2398,2,FALSE)`

Comment: @ScottCraner That worked! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Then your column D is text that looks like numbers and not numbers.  I would suggest instead of using a work around that you fix the actual problem by converting the text to numbers.